# Generic cache of objects

Tags: c++, stl, boost

Does anyone know any implementation of a templated cache of objects?

- You use a key to find object (the same as in std::map<>)
- You specify a maximum number of objects that can be in the cache at the same time
- There are facilities to create an object not found in the cache
- There are facilities to know when an object is discarded from the cache

For example :

```
typedef cache<int, MyObj*> MyCache;
MyCache oCache;
oCache.SetSize(1);
oCache.Insert(make_pair(1, new MyObj());
oCache.Touch(1);
MyObj* oldObj = oCache.Delete(1);

...
```

It can be as simple as a LRU or MRU cache.

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Nic

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) library.
It is easy to implement a [MRU cache](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example9).

Answer (score 1):

Ive put together a relatively simple LRU cache built from a map and a linked list:

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename Map = std::unordered_map<K, typename std::list<K>::iterator>>
class LRUCache
{
    size_t maxSize;
    Map data;
    std::list<K> usageOrder;
    std::function<void(std::pair<K, V>)> onEject = [](std::pair<K, V> x){};

    void moveToFront(typename std::list<K>::iterator itr)
    {
        if(itr != usageOrder.begin())
            usageOrder.splice(usageOrder.begin(), usageOrder, itr);
    }


    void trimToSize()
    {
        while(data.size() > maxSize)
        {
            auto itr = data.find(usageOrder.back());

            onEject(std::pair<K, V>(itr->first, *(itr->second)));
            data.erase(usageOrder.back());
            usageOrder.erase(--usageOrder.end());
        }
    }

public:
    typedef std::pair<const K, V> value_type;
    typedef K key_type;
    typedef V mapped_type;


    LRUCache(size_t maxEntries) : maxSize(maxEntries)
    {
        data.reserve(maxEntries);
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return data.size();
    }

    void insert(const value_type& v)
    {
        usageOrder.push_front(v.first);
        data.insert(typename Map::value_type(v.first, usageOrder.begin()));

        trimToSize();
    }

    bool contains(const K& k) const
    {
        return data.count(k) != 0;
    }

    V& at(const K& k)
    {
        auto itr = data.at(k);
        moveToFront(itr);
        return *itr;
    }


    void setMaxEntries(size_t maxEntries)
    {
        maxSize = maxEntries;
        trimToSize();
    }

    void touch(const K& k)
    {
        at(k);
    }

    template<typename Compute>
    V& getOrCompute(const K& k)
    {
        if(!data.contains(k)) insert(value_type(k, Compute()));
        return(at(k));
    }

    void setOnEject(decltype(onEject) f)
    {
        onEject = f;
    }
};
```

Which I believe meets your criteria. Anything need to be added, or changed?

Comment: The performance of map can easily become horrible. I'd suggest you use a hash table. Make it compile time fixed size, if you can. Instead of adding a list, scan it.

Comment: @BitWhistler This does use a hashtable- by default std::unordered_map which is a hash table. I don't think compile-time fixed size is a good idea at all- very low overhead to store the size and this allows the size to be changed as needed. What do you mean by instead of keeping a list, scan it? The list keeps track of the order of insertion so that the LRU entry can be deleted.

Comment: sorry, you're right. I thought I saw std::map. Still, preallocating everything will have the advantage of not reallocating. Reallocation is the biggest cost here. Same idea on the list. You'd have all these nodes floating around... better to have the age in the entries or have a singly linked list intrusive in the entries.

Answer (score -6):

In an application I can hardly imagine it would speed/boost up performance to store objects that apparently can be re-created (hip: since they can be automatically discarded, when the cache tops).
A sw cache would require memory-fetching through associativism code, surely slower then memory allocation and constructor running (mostly memory initializations).

With the exception of manual user configuration to avoid the paging mechanism (precisely to boost performance, btw), most OS "caches" memory for you on disk... it's "paging", a form of "high-cost caching", because nothing gets thrown away, and it's done by specific HW, a sub-processing unit called Memory Management Unit...

A caching-code, in the big picture, would be slowing processes while being redundant.

Comment: What if the (re)creation of an object is much slower than a key->value lookup?  Not every constructor is "mostly memory initializations."

Comment: I get why the downvote: I'm not providing an answer.
So I'm trying to get one:
Nowdays the MMU will flag the memory containing the non-recently used cached objects as low-usage, hence candidate to be sent to a page-file on the harddisk... assuming there's a HDD. So, re-fetching a missing cached-object from HDD, iso running code to re-create the object, would only in a very cumbersome set of circumstances be "right".
@Nicolas: what are your concrete circumstances?

Comment: I'm thinking you mix CPU cache and other type of data cache. OP looked for data cache, not CPU.