# C++ Memory Cache class

Tags: c++, mfc, std

I need a c++ class for caching my objects in memory with the ability to set expiring timeout.

Is there anything standard in std or mfc or do I need to implement it by myself?

Something like .NET MemoryCache class but in native C++.

Thanks,
Khachatur

Comment: Qt has a cache. http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qcache.html I was looking for one in boost for a non Qt usage but found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122914/generic-cache-of-objects

Comment: no, I don't want use the Qt.
Something more standard, like std or mfc or native Win32 API calls

Comment: My second link was a non Qt approach.

Comment: I was talking about the accepted answer for the similar question here. A direct link is here: http://patrickaudley.com/code/project/lrucache

Comment: Possibly even :http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4806/an-lru-cache-template

Comment: Or http://www.cs.uml.edu/~jlu1/doc/codes/lruCache.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Google lightweight c/c++ LRU memory cache (LRUC) project, that might be able to help you out, but without time out [lruc](https://code.google.com/p/lruc/)

By the best would be do know what you application is, since this would help for answering your question better.

Alternatively you can also implement pre-allocated memory which is useful in real-time systems. [memory-management-in-c-part-2](http://mflerackers.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/memory-management-in-c-part-2/)